# UIAutomator Viewer of Android SDK returns blank screenshot

Tags: android, sdk, android-uiautomator

I am new to Mobile automation testing using Android SDK , Appium.

Test Environment:-   Win-7, Android version 4.2.2

Steps that I followed :-

1. Connected the Android device version 4.2.2 using adb by commend

> `adb devices`

2. Navigate to folder C:\Users\android-sdks\tools and launched UIAutomatorviewer
3. click on "Device Screenshot" button of uiautomatorviewer

Instead of showing the connected mobile device screen it's returning the blank screenshot .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your SDK is not compatible with any one of the required JARS or Supportive software
 UIAutomator is not a separate one.. it will comes in your SDK suite.

Answer (score 1):

There many reason for this, Please take care of below points to make

1. your Emulator/Device is of below version  4.4 and sdk's >=19
2. check you device is connected to adb server by running  command on Cmd `adb devices` . Verify the device is listed
3. UIAutomator takes a simple screenshot of screen. So if screen saver is ON. means if your device screen get blank. then you click on "Device Screenshot". then the same blank image is return on UIautomator.
4. Some time UIAutomator is not fetch screen shot of your device. Try once again. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

It was an old bug for SDk's <=18. try to use Emulator/Device above 4.4 and recommend to use sdk's >=19

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60359